# Node.JS/MongoDB I can't access an object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need some help with my NodeJs project.

I'm trying to check the seller's name and then get it's internal 'support' to set the newOrder.support as the seller.support.

For some reason, it is not working and I have no idea why.
The `console.log(support)` inside of the `findOne()` it is showing the correct value, but the `console.log(support)` that I have just before my `newOrder = new Order({})` is showing that the value/datatype is 'undefined' so my database is storing data without the support value.

Could you guys help me out with it?
Thank you in advance.

```
    let support;
    User.findOne({
        fullName: seller
    }, function (err, user) {
        support = user.support;
        console.log(support);
    })
```

Comment: You didn't paste the whole code snippet, but it looks like you just need to wait for the promise returned from `findOne` before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⚠️ You can't set value `support` inside the Promise and than access them in outside("From your code").

So, if you want to access your value where you're using `findOne`, try to use `async/await`

If you're using in MongoDB, you can try this code below.

**Option 1: Inside mongoDB connection**

From mays, it's working with this code below: Only add `async/await`.

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', async (error, client) => {
  if(error) throw new Error(error);

  const db = client.db('blog_dev');
  const collection = db.collection('users');

  // start from here your async await
  let support = await collection.findOne({ fullName: 'Seller'});

  // you can get support now
  console.log(support);
})
```

**Option 2: From your code**

An example your code inside yourFunction(), then you can use code below:

```js
async function yourFunction() {
  const support = await User.findOne({ fullName: 'seller'});
  console.log(support);
}
```

I hope it's can help you.

Comment: This was 3 years ago haha but I never came back to check the answer! But that was definitely the right answer! Thanks Titus!

Comment: Thank you for come back to see this answer. It's mean after 3 years, you still alive. Hahaha, just kidding